# Convert an MS SQL Query to an Informix Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, informix

I am currently working on trying to convert the following MS SQL query to Informix, but I am not sure how.

```
SELECT     NumPlan.DNOrPattern, Device.Name, DeviceNumPlanMap.Display, TypeModel.Name AS Model, DeviceNumPlanMap.NumPlanIndex, 
                      Device.AddOnModules
FROM         DeviceNumPlanMap INNER JOIN
                      Device ON DeviceNumPlanMap.fkDevice = Device.pkid INNER JOIN
                      NumPlan ON DeviceNumPlanMap.fkNumPlan = NumPlan.pkid INNER JOIN
                      TypeModel ON Device.tkModel = TypeModel.Enum
WHERE     (TypeModel.Enum <> '10') AND (TypeModel.Enum <> '12') AND (TypeModel.Enum <> '120') AND (TypeModel.Enum <> '90') AND 
                      (TypeModel.Enum <> '73') and (TypeModel.Enum <> '72') and (TypeModel.Enum <> '80') AND (DeviceNumPlanMap.NumPlanIndex = '1') ORDER BY NumPlan.DNOrPattern, DeviceNumPlanMap.NumPlanIndex
```

Any help on how to convert this to an Informix query would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running it?  What error do you get?

Comment: It seems to not like the <> symbol

Comment: Normally, you use `!=` to indicate 'not equals' with Informix. I must admit I'd forgotten that the SQL standard demands `<>`. Fortunately, experimentation shows that Informix also accepts `<>` — tested with Informix 12.10.FC6 on Mac OS X 10.11.5.  Also consider the merits of `TypeModel.Enum NOT IN ('10', '12', '120', '90', '73', '72', '80')`.  When I run the query in the question against a set of empty tables, I get no syntax error.  Which version of Informix are you using, on which platform?  Are you using some intermediary software that mangles the SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In either database, I would write this query as:

```
SELECT np.DNOrPattern, d.Name, npm.Display, tm.Name AS Model, npm.NumPlanIndex, 
       d.AddOnModules
FROM DeviceNumPlanMap npm INNER JOIN
     Device d
     ON npm.fkDevice = d.pkid INNER JOIN
     NumPlan p
     ON npm.fkNumPlan = p.pkid INNER JOIN
     TypeModel tm
     ON d.tkModel = tm.Enum
WHERE tm.Enum NOT IN ('10', '12', '120', '90', '73', '72', '80') AND   
      npm.NumPlanIndex = '1'
ORDER BY np.DNOrPattern, npm.NumPlanIndex;
```

If the data types of `Enum` or `NumPlanIndex` are not strings, then remove the single quotes.

This should work in either database.  However, I think your original should as well.